# How to call stopPropagation in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I want to stop the click event from bubling up. Therefore I added e.stopPropagation() in my code. I always get a mistake in the console, that says: `Uncaught TypeError: e.stopPropagation is not a function`

What is the right way to set the stopPropagation in reactjs?

```
      handleClick: function(index, e) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        ...

    },
```

Comment: could you post your code? where do you call `handleClick`? Maybe in your first argument `Event` object - try call `console.log(typeof index.stopPropagation)`

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The right way is to use `.stopPropagation`,

```
var Component = React.createClass({
  handleParentClick: function() {
    console.log('handleParentClick');
  },

  handleChildClick: function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    console.log('handleChildClick');
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div onClick={this.handleParentClick}>
      <p onClick={this.handleChildClick}>Child</p>
    </div>;
  }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/4z2vyrw9/)

> Your event handlers will be passed instances of SyntheticEvent, a
>   cross-browser wrapper around the browser's native event. It has the
>   same interface as the browser's native event, including
>   stopPropagation() and preventDefault(), except the events work
>   identically across all browsers.
>   [`Event System`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
export default function myComponent(){

    //buttonClicked:
    const buttonClicked = (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        // your code here...
    }

    //return:
    return (
        <div>
            <input type='button'
                onClick={ (e) => buttonClicked(e) }
            ></input>
        </div>
    )

}
```