# stopPropagation in two click handler doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<div onClick={e => this.openDetail}>
  <div onClick{e => this.handleLike} />
     like
  </div>
</div>
```

How does `e.stopPropagation();` work in react? I tried put that in both handler, `openDetail` will always fire.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914680/how-to-call-stoppropagation-in-reactjs

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo for stackoverflow but you miss a '=' on the second div.