# How to stop event propagation in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have tried doing `e.stopPropagation();` and `e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();`

This is what my code looks like for the child component:

```
class S extends React.Component {
  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class='box' onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But in the parent component, the event for click still gets triggered

Any ideas??
Thanks

Comment: As a side point, `class` should be `className`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call stopPropagation in reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914680/how-to-call-stoppropagation-in-reactjs)

Comment: Another point: if event propagation is the only thing you need to do in event handler, there is no reason to bind it, as event is passed as an argument.

Comment: I changed it to us `class` instead of `className`, and the reason for binding is for future purposes

Comment: @Nayish tried their soln but didn't work :S

Comment: Also just noticed that the parent's click event handler gets trigger first and not the child...