# React button onClick referencing SVG and not the event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, events, fonts

I'm trying to pass on the value of a button to a function, however when the button is clicked the event is coming from the SVG and not from the button itself, when I click the button right on the edge where the SVG is not present the event fires normally. How can I make the SVG to be ignored in the onClick? I want the event to be from the button and not from the SVG. I am using Font Awesome and importing icons through the React library.

JSX:

```
 <button className="btn-vote" value={site._id} name="1" onClick={handleVote}>{upSVG} 
 </button>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-vote {
  font-size: 1.9vw;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Does handleVote use this or does it use event.target?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use css property pointer-events for your **upSVG**, then it will be ignored when you clicked on the button.

```
   pointer-events: none;
```

Hope it will be fixed your issue.

Else you can call a function to stopPropagation like this.

```
<svg onClick={e=> e.stopPropagation(); }/>
```

Comment: perfect exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have an event surfacing, look here - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914680/how-to-call-stoppropagation-in-reactjs,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914680/how-to-call-stoppropagation-in-reactjs)

```
function App () {
  const handleVote = e => console.log(e)

  const stopPropagation = e => e.stopPropagation()
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <MyComponent />
      <button
        className='btn-vote'
        value={'fdsdfsd'}
        name='1'
        onClick={handleVote}
      >
        <i onClick={stopPropagation} className='fab fa-500px'></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```