# Ignoring parent or child's event handler

Tags: reactjs

I have part of a React Component that looks like this:

```
<div onClick={() => handleTriggerParent()}>
    <button type='button' onClick={() => handleTriggerChildren()}>
         Children
    </button>
</div>
```

I want to ignore `handleTriggerParent()` method when `handleTriggerChildren()` method is triggered.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call stopPropagation in reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914680/how-to-call-stoppropagation-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Define the `button`'s click handler like so:

```
onClick={(e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  handleTriggerChildren();
}}
```