# Why my react click bubbles up in spite of all stopPropagations?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that has a child component deep inside it.

In the click event of child component, I have this code:

```
onClick={(e) => {
    // do something related to the deep child component
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.nativeEvent.stopPropagation()
}}
```

But this event still bubbles up and the `onClick` handler of my parent component is still fired.

I read about [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) and I also saw these questions. But none of them solved my problem:

[ReactJS SyntheticEvent stopPropagation() only works with React events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415631/reactjs-syntheticevent-stoppropagation-only-works-with-react-events)

[How to call stopPropagation in reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914680/how-to-call-stoppropagation-in-reactjs)

[How can I prevent event bubbling in nested React components on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619981/how-can-i-prevent-event-bubbling-in-nested-react-components-on-click)

Comment: Have you tried `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: @SerhiiHolinei, I added both `e.preventDefault()` and `e.nativeEvent.preventDefault()` but it still fires my parent's `onClick`. Though I think `e.preventDefault()` is all about links and default behavior of elements, not propagation.

Comment: Seems like something else is going on in your setup as calling `stopPropagtion` works. see: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-hellman-40qoj. Maybe share some more of the code that contains this component and how it's used

Comment: @thedude it's a real-world application with a lot of complications. I can't share code, because I really don't know what to post here. I just want to know how can I debug it. React's docs are not very informative, or maybe I don't understand them.

Comment: I suggest you try to create a minimal example that reproduces this issue. It will also help you isolate the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try using onClickCapture() here instead of onClick().

https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#supported-events

Comment: I read the docs, and it does not explain what `capture` is. What does that do?