# React - Child Components trigger click effect on parent

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a react component (a Card), that will trigger a function if the card is pressed. However, I have child components within this component that will perform their own actions (sliders, buttons, etc.)  When clicking on these child elements, I do not want the parent element to run its onclick or click "effect" (go "active").

How could I "omit" or ignore the parent's properties when I click on a child component?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add *all* the relevant code.

Comment: React events have a `stopPropagation` method that works in the same way as vanilla JS, you can prevent the events bubbling up to the card. [How to call stopPropagation in reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914680/how-to-call-stoppropagation-in-reactjs)

Comment: @DBS, that's right, Thank you. I come back to react after periods of not using from time to time.

Comment: stopPropagation Works, thank you.  However, it is the Pseudo :active class I want to prevent also.

From my research, it would seem the best way to prevent the pseudo would be to apply a class dynamically. would that be correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```js
const handleChildClick = (event: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
  event.stopPropagation(); // prevent event to propagate to parent
  // things you want to do for this click
};
```